# Inline math seems to be screwing up line spacing in my dissertation (inline math seems to result in less spacing!)

Tags: pdftex, report

I am in the process of writing my dissertation with the template provided by my institution (https://gradschool.utexas.edu/academics/theses-and-dissertations/digital-submission-requirement/latex-document-preparation). I am getting some weirdness with vertical spacing that seems to occur when I use inline math; I say this because it tends to be ameliorated when make I make some inline equations "aligned". Weirdly, it seems to make the spacing "less" rather than more (which would make sense).  That said, I cannot figure out the rhyme or reason, and it might be that it has something to do with the length of paragraphs, or latex not wanting to "break up" certain environments over multiple pages. I've attached an example. Does anyone have any advice on how to ameliorate this? The whole thing is supposed to be double spaced, but you can see that the last paragraph is squished... [image]

Main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}    % The documentclass must be ``report''.

\usepackage{utdiss2}        % Dissertation package style file.
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amscd} 
                %
\usepackage{eucal}      % Euler fonts
\usepackage{verbatim}       % Allows quoting source with commands.
\usepackage{makeidx}        % Package to make an index.
\usepackage{epsfig}             % Allows inclusion of eps           % 
\usepackage{url}        % Allows good typesetting of web URLs.

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\topmargin 0.125in  

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{ax}{Axiom}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}


we must demonstrate that the KL divergences $D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\left.\mathbf{q}_{{t}}||\mathbf{q}\right|\boldsymbol{\delta}_{{t}}),D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\mathbf{q}_{{t}}||\mathbf{q})$ tend to $0$ as ${t} \rightarrow \infty$. This is the subject of the following lemma.  
\begin{lemma}
We have that both \begin{align}
    \lim_{{t}\rightarrow\infty} D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\left.\mathbf{q}_{{t}}||\mathbf{q}\right|\boldsymbol{\delta}_{{t}}) =0 \text{ and }\lim_{{t}\rightarrow\infty} D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\mathbf{q}_{{t}}||\mathbf{q}) =0.
\end{align} 
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
 It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}$ are random variables that are absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure such that $\mathbf{a}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mathbf{b}$, then $D_{\mathrm{KL}}(Q_{{\Delta}}(\mathbf{a})||Q_{{\Delta}}(\mathbf{b}))\le D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\mathbf{a}||\mathbf{b})$. Thus, 
  we have $D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\mathbf{q}_{{t}}||\mathbf{q}) \le D_{\mathrm{KL}}(C\mathbf{e}_{{t}}+\boldsymbol{\delta}_{{t}}||C\mathbf{e}+\boldsymbol{\delta})$. Since $\boldsymbol{\delta}_{{t}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\delta}$ are identically distributed, $\mathbf{e}_{{t}}\perp\boldsymbol{\delta}_{{t}}$, and $\mathbf{e}\perp\boldsymbol{\delta}$,  the data processing inequality (DPI) for KL divergences (cf. [44, Theorem 2.15]) gives $  D_{\mathrm{KL}}(C\mathbf{e}_{{t}}+\boldsymbol{\delta}_{{t}}||C\mathbf{e}+\boldsymbol{\delta})\le D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\mathbf{e}_{{t}}||\mathbf{e})$.
The proof that $D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\left.\mathbf{q}_{{t}}||\mathbf{q}\right|\boldsymbol{\delta}_{{t}})\le D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\mathbf{e}_{{t}}||\mathbf{e})$ is analogous. To begin, recognize that for each $\delta \in [-\frac{{\Delta}}{2},\frac{{\Delta}}{2}]^n$,  $D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\left.\mathbf{q}_{{t}}||\mathbf{q}\right|\boldsymbol{\delta}_{{t}}=\delta)\le D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\left.C\mathbf{e}_{{t}}+\delta|| C\mathbf{e}+\delta \right|\boldsymbol{\delta}_{{t}}=\delta)$ where both $\mathbf{e}_{{t}}\perp \boldsymbol{\delta}_{{t}}$ and $\mathbf{e}\perp \boldsymbol{\delta}_{{t}}$. Applying the DPI for every realization $\delta$ and using the fact that, by independence, $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbf{e}_{{t}}|\boldsymbol{\delta}_{{t}}} = \mathbb{P}_{\mathbf{e}_{{t}}}$ and likewise  $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbf{e}|\boldsymbol{\delta}} = \mathbb{P}_{\mathbf{e}}$ completes the argument. Thus, we can prove the lemma by demonstrating that $\lim_{{t}\rightarrow\infty} D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\mathbf{e}_{{t}}||\mathbf{e})=0$.

Let $\{\boldsymbol{\nu}_{{t}}\}$ denote an IID sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on $[-{\Delta}/2,{\Delta}/2]^{{m}}$, let $\{\boldsymbol{\omega}_{{t}}\}$ be IID with $\boldsymbol{\omega}_{{t}}\in\mathcal{N}(0_{{m}},W)$, and let $\boldsymbol{\lambda}\sim\mathcal{N}(0_{{m}},X_{0})$. Assume $\{\boldsymbol{\omega}_{{t}}\}$, $\{\boldsymbol{\nu}_{{t}}\}$, and $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ are mutually independent. Let ``$\overset{D}{=}$" denote ``equality in distribution", e.g., we write $\mathbf{a}\overset{D}{=}\mathbf{b}$ to imply $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are identically distributed. From (22), we have $\mathbf{e}_{{t}} =R\mathbf{e}_{{t}-1} -L\mathbf{v}_{{t}-1}+\mathbf{w}_{{t}-1}$. Via Prop. 4 Claim (iii) and the factorization of system variables in (44), it can be verified that $\mathbf{w}_{{t}}\perp \mathbf{e}^{{t}}, \mathbf{v}^t,\mathbf{w}^{{t}-1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{{t}}\perp \mathbf{e}^{{t}}, \mathbf{v}^{{t}-1},\mathbf{w}^{{t}}$.
Thus, by this recursive definition of $\{\mathbf{e}_{{t}}\}$, $ \mathbf{e}_{{t}} \overset{D}{=} R^{{t}}\boldsymbol{\lambda}+\sum_{{i}=0}^{{t}-1}R^{{i}}(\boldsymbol{\omega}_{{i}}-L\boldsymbol{\nu}_{{i}}). $
 Likewise, by definition of $\mathbf{e}$, we have that both $\mathbf{e} \overset{D}{=} \lim_{{t}\rightarrow\infty}R^{{t}}\boldsymbol{\lambda}+\sum_{{i}=0}^{{t}-1}R^{{i}}(\boldsymbol{\omega}_{{i}}-L\boldsymbol{\nu}_{{i}})$ and $\mathbf{e} \overset{D}{=}\lim_{{t}\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{{i}=0}^{{t}-1}R^{{i}}(\boldsymbol{\omega}_{{i}}-L\boldsymbol{\nu}_{{i}})$, which follows since Lemma 5's convergence in total variation implies weak convergence. 
We have
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
    D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\mathbf{e}_{{t}}|| \mathbf{e} ) &=&   D_{\mathrm{KL}}(R^{{t}}\boldsymbol{\lambda}+\mathbf{g}_{\le {t}} +\mathbf{u}_{\le {t}}||\mathbf{g}_{\le {t}} +\mathbf{u}_{\le {t}}+\mathbf{s}_{>{t}} )\nonumber \\ &\le& D_{\mathrm{KL}}(R^{{t}}\boldsymbol{\lambda}+\mathbf{g}_{\le {t}}||\mathbf{g}_{\le {t}} +\mathbf{s}_{>{t}} )\label{eq:usedidiv} \\ &\le& D_{\mathrm{KL}}(\left.R^{{t}}\boldsymbol{\lambda}+\mathbf{g}_{\le {t}} || \mathbf{g}_{\le {t}}+\mathbf{s}_{>{t}} \right| \mathbf{s}_{>{t}} ),\label{eq:condincdiv}  
\end{IEEEeqnarray} where (\ref{eq:usedidiv}) follows from the data processing inequality for KL divergence and (\ref{eq:condincdiv}) follows since conditioning increases KL divergence (see [44, Theorem 2.14 (e)]).
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Header:

```
% Dimension Setting %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Top margin is now set in the disstemplate.tex file.
%                   29 Nov 2001 cwm

\oddsidemargin 0.625in \evensidemargin 0.625in
\textwidth 5.5in
\headheight .21in
\headsep .29in  % \headheight + \headsep = 0.5in
\textheight 8in % \textheight includes \footskip
\footskip .5in

\skip\footins 22.8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt
\parindent .5in
\parskip 5 pt plus 1.5pt minus .5pt
\itemsep 0 pt plus .5pt

\pagenumbering{roman}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Macros to Modify Some Default Settings of `report.sty'. %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Macros to make:
%       the text height of the first page of every chapter
%       = \textheight - \footskip
%
\newlength{\regular@textheight}
\setlength{\regular@textheight}{\textheight}
%
\addtolength{\regular@textheight}{-\footskip}
            % Added -\footskip to move bottom
            % page numbers on non-first-page-of-chapter
            % pages up so they meet the Graduate School
            % spec.     24 Sep 2001 cwm
\newlength{\short@textheight}
\setlength{\short@textheight}{\textheight}
\addtolength{\short@textheight}{-\footskip}

\def\short@page{%
    \setlength{\textheight}{\short@textheight}
    \global \pagestyle{plain}   % Added to put page numbers
                % at bottom of short pages.
                %   24 Sep 2001 cwm
    \global \@colht\textheight
    \global \@colroom\textheight
    \global \vsize\textheight}
\def\regular@page{%
    \setlength{\textheight}{\regular@textheight}
    \global \pagestyle{plain}   % Added to put page numbers
                % at bottom of regular pages.
                %   24 Sep 2001 cwm
    \global \@colht\textheight
    \global \@colroom\textheight
    \global \vsize\textheight}

\newcounter{regular@short}

\let\old@opcol\@opcol
\def\@opcol{%
    \ifnum\value{regular@short}=0 \regular@page\old@opcol
    \else\short@page\old@opcol\fi}

% Regarding the space after the zero in the value setting above:
%
% "For best results, ALWAYS PUT A BLANK SPACE AFTER A NUMERIC CONSTANT;
%  this blank space tells TeX that the constant is complete, and
%  such a space will never "get through" to the output."
% " ... a missing space ... might cause TeX to expand macros when you
%  don't want any expansion, and such anomalies can cause subtle and
%  confusing errors"
%       - the TeXbook, p. 208.          cwm

%
% Macros to set spacing of text and quotations.
%                          ^^^^ ^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^
\def\single@space{%
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \baselineskip=15.5pt plus .5pt minus .2pt
    \vskip-\baselineskip}
\def\endsingle@space{\par}

\def\oneandonehalf@space{%
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \baselineskip=20.5pt plus .5pt minus .2pt
    \vskip-\baselineskip}
\def\endoneandonehalf@space{\par}

\def\double@space{%
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \baselineskip=23.5pt plus .5pt minus .2pt
    \vskip-\baselineskip}
\def\enddouble@space{\par}

%
% Regular text spacing
%
\def\doublespacing{%
    \def\default@spacing{\baselineskip=23.5pt plus .5pt minus .2pt}}
\def\oneandonehalfspacing{%
    \def\default@spacing{\baselineskip=20.5pt plus .5pt minus .2pt}}
\def\singlespacing{%
    \def\default@spacing{\baselineskip=15.5pt plus .5pt minus .2pt}}




%
% Stolen from `report.sty'. Modified to change the size of left skip
%     for \chapter title which is longer than one line.
%
\newlength{\toc@chap@indent}
\settowidth{\toc@chap@indent}{\bf\@chapapp\space\thechapter.\hspace*{1em}}
\def\l@chapter#1#2{\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}
    \vskip 1.0em plus 1pt
    \@tempdima=\toc@chap@indent
    \begingroup
    \parindent \z@
    \rightskip \@pnumwidth
    \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
    \bf \leavevmode
    \advance\leftskip\@tempdima \hskip -\leftskip #1\nobreak\hfil
    \nobreak\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \penalty\@highpenalty \endgroup}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{ \vspace*{0pt} {\parindent 0pt \centering
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \Large\bf \@chapapp{} \thechapter
    \par \vskip 15pt \fi \Large \bf #1\par \nobreak \vskip 35pt}}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\vspace*{0pt} {\parindent 0pt \centering
    \Large \bf #1\par \nobreak \vskip 30pt}}

\def\chapter{%
    \clearpage
    \short@page \setcounter{regular@short}{0}   %<<--
    \default@spacing
%
% Comment out one of the two lines below to determine indention of
%   first lines of chapters.    28 Sep 2001 cwm
%
    \global\@topnum\z@ \@afterindenttrue    % Indent 1st line of chapter.
%    \global\@topnum\z@ \@afterindentfalse  % Do NOT indent 1st line
                        %   of chapter.
    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}

\def\shortchapter{%
    \clearpage
    \short@page \setcounter{regular@short}{1}   %<<--
    \default@spacing
%
% Comment out one of the two lines below to determine indention of
%   first lines of short chapters.  28 Sep 2001 cwm
%
    \global\@topnum\z@ \@afterindenttrue    % Indent 1st line of short
                        %   chapter.
%    \global\@topnum\z@ \@afterindentfalse  % Do NOT indent 1st line
                        %   of short chapter.
    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}

\newcount\chap@or@app\chap@or@app=1




% Redefinition of \@part for using by \part (M.A.L.)
%
\newcount\with@parts\with@parts=0 % <- this would allow to restart 
                                  %    page number with Chapter 1 (MAL)
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \short@page                   % <- Added 4/21/97 (MAL)
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2 \relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%        % Added \partname~ below (M.A.L.)
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\partname~\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \reset@font
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2 \relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname~\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
     \ifnum\value{part}=1 \pagenumbering{arabic}%  % if Part I
     \with@parts=1 \fi%  % <- to avoid restarting page number with chapter 1
    \@endpart}
%
%%%% End redefinition of \@part



\newcounter{no@chapters}                       % (7/16/97 M.A.L.)
\setcounter{no@chapters}{0}                    % 

\newcommand\nochapters{%                       %
\setcounter{no@chapters}{1}                    % (7/16/97 M.A.L.)
\fpage  \setcounter{regular@short}{0}          %
%
% Comment out one of the two lines below to determine indention of
%   first lines of text with no chapters.
%                   28 Sep 2001 cwm
%
    \global\@topnum\z@ \@afterindenttrue    % Indent 1st lines.
%    \global\@topnum\z@ \@afterindentfalse  % Do NOT indent 1st lines.
                                               %
\pagenumbering{arabic}                         % Added for using with 
\markboth{}{}\pagestyle{myheadings}            % no chapters
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}  % (4/22/97, MAL)


\default@spacing                               % (6/30/97 M.A.L.)
                                               %
}                                              % 

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne 
    \refstepcounter{chapter}
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.\hspace*{1em}#1}\else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}\fi
    % \chaptermark{#1}
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
    \@makechapterhead{#2} \@afterheading
    \ifnum\chap@or@app=1 \ifnum\value{chapter}=1         % if Chapter 1
        \markboth{}{}\pagestyle{myheadings}
        \ifnum\with@parts=0 \pagenumbering{arabic}\fi% Restart page number only
                                                 % if there are no parts (MAL)
                                           \fi\fi 
        \thispagestyle{plain}}

\def\@schapter#1{\thispagestyle{plain}
        \@makeschapterhead{#1} \@afterheading}


\doublespacing
```

Edit: Added example that illustrates the problem (although on multiple pages). See also https://www.overleaf.com/read/ddgbkzmnqsjn. I have trimmed the header to eliminate superfluous commands, etc.

Comment: Looks like the extra spacing is already present at the start of your picture. Where does it start? What do you do there? Can you provide a small complete example where this happens? Code, not just an image.

Comment: Sure, I think I've got something.

Comment: Perhaps this has something to do using IEEEeqnarray in the proof environment? Anyway, here's a link with a pretty minimal example: https://www.overleaf.com/read/ddgbkzmnqsjn.

Comment: Please post your (possibly minimal) code /here/. Links to external pages are discouraged as they will likely disappear making the question meaningless.

Comment: no document written this century should be using `epsfig`

Comment: I assume the utdiss2 package provides the double spacing.  Start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unrelated to inline math, deleting unrelated code from your example produces a more resonable example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}    % The documentclass must be ``report''.



                %
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\makeatletter
\def\doublespacing{%
    \def\default@spacing{\baselineskip=23.5pt plus .5pt minus .2pt}}

\doublespacing\default@spacing
\topmargin 0.125in  

\begin{document}
\doublespacing\default@spacing
\chapter{Introduction}




 It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if  It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if 
 It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if  It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if 
 It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if  It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if 
 It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if  It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if 
 It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if  It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if 
 It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if  It can be shown via Jensen's inequality that if 

denote an IID sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on
denote an IID sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on
denote an IID sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on
denote an IID sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on
denote an IID sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on
denote an IID sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on
denote an IID sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on
denote an IID sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on
denote an IID sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
a&=&b
\end{IEEEeqnarray} 

\end{document}
```

The problem is the way the `utdss2` defines `\doublespace` changing the baslineskip in a way that means any latex size command such  as `\normalsize` will lose the setting. You could use instead the`setspace` package or for a quick fix put a blank line before the eqnarray.